# Filter in the drop down data -Angular 6

Tags: javascript, html, json, angular

I want Angular app to filter data from the dropdown, list of products are associated with the product number. Below is the JSON structure.

**component.ts**

```js
productlistArray = [{
    number: "1",
    productlist: [
        { name: "product_1_0" },
        { name: "product_1_1" }
    ]
}, {
    number: "2",
    productlist: [
        { name: "product_2_0" },
        { name: "product_2_1" }
    ]
}];

onclickx() {
    this.consoleMessages += "called this function";
}
```

I have an input box (to search by product). when I type product number it must list only products under product number.

**component.html**

```html
<td>  
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search By Product No" style="width:300px" [(ngModel)]="searchTerm"/>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <mat-select (selectionChange)="onclickx($event.value)">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let product of productlistArray" [value]="product.number">
                {{product.productlist}}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </div> 
</td>
```

**pipe.ts**

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name:"ProductFilter",
    pure:true
})
export class ProductFilter implements PipeTransform {
    transform(data: any[], searchTerm: string): any[] {
        return data.filter(productlistArray =>(productlistArray.number == searchTerm));
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you having with your code?

Comment: Where do you use your pipe?

Comment: Please take a read: https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe So first of all, move the logic to the component instead :)

Answer (score 0):

Initially, when there is no `searchTerm` entered, it will be `undefined` so the filter will not return any `data`. Add a condition to return all `data` if there is no `searchTerm`. As mentioned by @AJT82 in the comments, this logic should also be placed in the component.

```js
filteredProducts: any; // You should ideally create an interface instead
searchTerm: string;

filter() {
    this.filteredProducts = this.searchTerm ? this.productlistArray.filter(productlistArray => productlistArray.number == this.searchTerm) : this.productlistArray;
}
```

**Note**: For `formControl`, use `valueChanges` to achieve the same

Then call this function on `change` of the `input`

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="searchTerm" (change)="filter()" placeholder="Search By Product No" style="width: 300px;" />
```

And use `filteredProducts` in your template

```html
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select placeholder="Product" (selectionChange)="onclickx($event.value)">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let product of filteredProducts" [value]="product.number">
            {{product.productlist}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Btw, `product.productlist` is an array of object, there's nothing mentioned in the question regarding that. What do you actually want to display in the dropdown?

Comment: I want to display all the products pertaining to product number entered

Comment: So, there is no need for pipe instead I create an interface

Comment: I'm not sure how creating an interface will solve this issue. Also for multiple product names, you can't use the same `value`.